# Java JRE-8u66 installer does not start

Tags: windows-8, firefox, java, jre, java-applet

I'm trying to install Java JRE update 66 (latest update) but when I click the installer nothing happens. The process is visible in the task manager but without any function.

[image: Java in Task Manager]
 I have could install older versions of JRE 8, namely update 45 but it wasn't recognised by any internet browser. The installer did work on my other PC, therefore, I uninstalled all versions of java and installed all the Windows updates but all didn't help.
I also tried to change the capability. It did not work, too.
Any help?

Update: I was unable to check out why the installer (from Oracle) not starting. Though I installed it using [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) installer.

Comment: You have the required user permissions to launch the installer?

Comment: yes. I tried though running it as admin